# Exchange Online: Configure Room Finder in Outlook

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

In Exchange Online, you have the ability to set booking delegates on room mailboxes. You can then also either set to auto accept meetings from only these people or have them approve each meeting request manually from any user.

We have multiple room mailboxes locked down so that only a handful of users can book these rooms.

Is there a way to configure the room finder in Outlook to exclude the non-bookable from displaying?

Currently, there is no indication visible to the user during the setup process of a meeting if whether they have the permission to book the chosen room or not.

I researched this online but couldn’t really find anything.

Comment: Your quickest path to resolution would be to open a support ticket with Office 365 from your tenant. It's free of charge.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid we are not able to manage what rooms are show in room finder, or you may consider adding a mailtip for those room mailboxes to notify the users who want to book them. And the suggested way above opening a service request: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide